# Conditionally update Dataframe from second dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes and would like to use the second to update the first. The problem though is that the second dataframe consists of all entries but either with different amounts of data (as shown below)

```
DF1                     DF2                   DF3
 X    Y                X    Y                X   Y
 1    A                1    B                1   B
 2    <NA>             2    B                2   B
 3    <NA>             3    C         -->    3   C
 4    D                4    <NA>             4   D
 5    E                5    <NA>             5   E
```

It should be a simple update query where entries in DF1 updates if DF2 is not NA

I first thought of removing the NA from the list

```
DF2sub <- subset(DF2,!is.na(Y)
DF3 <- transform(DF1, Y = DF2sub$Y[match(X,DF2sub$X)])
```

but the resulting code does the following

```
DF3
X    Y
X    Y    
 1    B
 2    B
 3    C
 4    <NA>
 5    <NA>
```

Comment: i wrote a post about this: https://alistaire.rbind.io/blog/coalescing-joins/

Comment: but assigning to a subset with a boolean mask can be helpful: `DF1[is.na(DF1)] <- DF2[is.na(DF1)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use the which function to obtain the indices of the NA and not NA values and map it together. like this.

```
DF3 <- rbind(DF2[which(!is.na(DF2$Y)),],DF1[which(is.na(DF2$Y)),])
```

Hope this solves your issue.